# How to restrict Rsync update timestamp

Tags: rsync

```
rsync -av --size-only --include="*/" --include="*.jpeg" --exclude="*" ~/alg/temperature/ ~/alg/tmp/
```

I use command as above to sync some files, and I don't want to update anything even timestamp if file size is the same

the option --size-only could only sync the file which changed in size

but those which no change in size will be "touched" and update the timestamp, this is what I don't want

how could I make it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The -a option is equivalent to -rlptgoD. You need to remove the -t. -t tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update them on the remote system.
You may want to try the `-c skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size`. This is slower, but should work for what you want. 
So your line could be (by expanding a and replacing t with c):
    `rsync -rlpcgoDv --include="*/" --include="*.jpeg" --exclude="*" ~/alg/temperature/ ~/alg/tmp/`

Comment: `rsync -rlvi` sets all the file modification timestamps to now.. I think the goal was to not change them at all, based on the asker saying the files will be "touched and update the timestamp".

Comment: @adfaklsdjf - using the timestamps is the default behavior. So not specifying -c, as in your example, will touch the files.

Comment: It would be nice if rsync could use modification timestamps on both ends to determine what needs to be transferred, without then modifying those timestamps on either side. Perhaps there's some technical reason why this isn't possible to implement, but I'm not able to think of one.

Thanks.